# Which proxy mode to use if host company terminates TLS on reverse proxy

Tags: ssl, keycloak, reverse-proxy, tls1.2, traefik

*Friendly Disclaimer: I am new to working with Keycloak and IdP in general. So it's likely that I use incorrect terminology and/or am more confused than I think I am. Corrections are gratefully accepted.*

My question is conceptual.

I have a TLS certificate that is terminated on my host machine by my host company. My reverse proxy (Traefik) is picking up that certificate.

Which of the following proxy modes should I use now to be able to deploy Keycloak to production: **edge, reencrypt or passthrough**? (see [here](https://www.keycloak.org/server/reverseproxy) for relevant documentation)

I can pretty much rule out passthrough, because as I wrote, the TLS certificate is terminated on the server. But I am unsure if I have to bring my own certificate and reencrypt or if it is considered safe to go along with edge?

*I have done my best to keep this question short and general. However, I am happy to share configurations or further details if needed.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, most organizations consider a request to be safe when the proxy validated and terminated the TLS. It also removes the performance overhead (depends on your load). Unless your organization is going for Zero Trust for its internal network, using the `edge` should be totally acceptable.